# How can I compare multiple strings in an if statement with Java?

Tags: java, string, if-statement

I'm not entirely certain how to word this. I'm wanting to know how to check if one of several strings is present in a variable.
I was told this would work, however it isn't do what I expect.

```
       String lett2array=arr[i];
       String[] lett=lett2array.split("");
       int y = 0;
       while(y != lett.length){
           if(lett[1].equals("a")||lett[1].equals("e")||lett[1].equals("i")||lett[1].equals("o")||lett[1].equals("u")){
               inputField.append(" \n"+lett[y]);
           }
```

Comment: What are you trying to do *exactly*?

Comment: What is the type of `lett`? And what are you trying to do?

Comment: Please show how `lett` is set

Comment: Are you sure it's | (bytes XOR) and not || (or operator) ?

Comment: The || didn't work either, I guess I should have mentioned that

Comment: @jidma: your concept of operators is mistaken. `|` is not a byte-wise xor but rather can work as a logical or.

Comment: Are you sure you want `lett[1]` and not `lett[y]`?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels: `|` is bitwise or. A boolean has only one bit, so in that case it behaves as a logical or.

Comment: @user1640491: post some more of the code you used, maybe the problem isn't this piece

Comment: @Eric: I know that `|` is a bit-wise OR. But it's not a bit-wise XOR as was suggested by jidma.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels: Whoops, misread that. You're correct there.

Comment: @ruakh yeah, I only want to test against the second value of the array (The array is full of letters)

Comment: Your `while(y != lett.length)` loop will never terminate, because neither `lett.length` nor `y` changes.

Comment: @Eric this part was truncated, I figured it would be obvious I would have a y++ later in the code.

Comment: @user1640491: Why would you not use a for loop?

Comment: I completely agree with Eric.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is written in a very roundabout way.

1. There's no point checking the second letter of the string every loop - check it beforehand, and store the result
2. Don't use `.split("")` when all you want is a character array
3. Use a for loop rather than iterating with a while loop

Here's how I'd write it:

```
String str = arr[i];
char[] letters = str.toCharArray();

boolean secondLetterIsVowel = letters[1] == 'a'
                           || letters[1] == 'e'
                           || letters[1] == 'i'
                           || letters[1] == 'o'
                           || letters[1] == 'u';
for(char letter : letters) {
    if(secondLetterIsVowel) {
        inputField.append(" \n" + letter);
    }
    //...
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be `lett[0]`? Just asking, because arrays in Java start with index `0`. I'm not even sure that he wants to do this, though. I think that he just wants to go through a string and only output the vowels.

Comment: From the comments on the question, "_yeah, I only want to test against the second value of the array_"

Comment: OK. My bad. I'll remove my erroneous answer.

Comment: @eboix: I guess I made that misleading with `startsWithVowel`. Changed to `secondLetterIsVowel`!

Comment: Actually this is my bad, after testing this (The only one that works as I want it to) it turns out I do want the first index. Sorry, I'm quite tired at the moment and I'm making a lot of mistakes, but everyone starts somewhere I guess. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `||`, not `|`

```
if(lett[1].equals("a") || lett[1].equals("e") || lett[1].equals("i") || lett[1].equals("o") || lett[1].equals("u")) {
    inputField.append(" \n"+lett[y]);
}
```

`|` is the bitwise or operator, while `||` is the short-circuiting logical or operator.

Comment: Are you sure it makes that much of difference? I am not.

Comment: @BorisStrandjev: Using `||` is more efficient, because it stops evaluting when it hits a true.

Comment: This is right in most cases, because comparing with `|` will force all comparisons, while comparing with `||` will stop after the one of the comparison evaluated to `true`.

Comment: @Eric True, thanks for elaborating, but this time I just wanted to point out this will not solve the OPs problem (whatever it is)

Comment: In this case (specifically), there is no logical difference between them.

Answer (score 1):

Use Apache Commons:

```
StringUtils.startsWithAny(String  string, String [] searchStrings)
```

More info: http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

You've used | (bit-wise OR) instead of || (logical OR)

Whenever you want to 'test condition one or condition 2', use '||'.

Comment: `|` also is a logical or, but it just doesn't fail fast.

Comment: In this case it doesn't matter, but you're right, in general you should use `||`

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels: Dude, I just love the rate with which you cast downvotes. I think this is your fourth I have seen in less than 4 minutes...

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels: Not sure about the terminology you used, but it is usually called short-circuit evaluation.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html

Comment: @tb189: I'm not saying that you can't use this as a bit-wise or, but it also is a logical or as well. It just doesn't have a short-cut exit like `||` does.

Answer (score 0):

If you have something like this:

```
if( a.equals( b ) || a.equals( c ) || a.equals( d ) )
```

You can rewrite it as:

```
if( Arrays.asList( b,c,d).contains( a ) )
```

And of course if b,c and d are constants, you can create the list as a constant too.

Comment: Isn't this far less efficient?

Comment: @Eric If you create the array every time, it is. If you can extract it into a constant, it is pretty much the same. It almost certainly doesn't matter in practice though. (If you have many values to compare with, you should of course use a `Set` instead.)

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution. Use `charAt(int index)` instead of `split`, which is O(n) time complexity, and compare `chars`, not `String`s, it's faster.

```
    String currString = arr[i]; // Get the current string
    char secondLet = currString.charAt(1); // Get the second letter

    // chars are primitive, so == will suffice
    if(secondLet == 'a' || secondLet == 'e'
        || secondLet == 'i' || secondLet == 'o' || secondLet == 'u') {
        // The second letter is a vowel!
        // Do whatever you want to do.......
        // I didn't understand if you wanted to output the whole String,
        // Or just the vowels. Whatever. Just do what you want.
    }
```